# Why is my css Media Queries not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am making my nav bar responsive using the dev tools responsive sizings of chrome. I want to costumize the nav bar for a max-width of 400px as you will see in the code, altought the navbar is not changing when I inspect the mobiles sizing that I am costumizing (mobile S and mobile M). Here is a print of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sjst.jpg

Appreciate any help!

Here is the code of the nav bar: https://jsfiddle.net/5syoxzch/

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.ulSecções');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.ulSecções li');

    //Toggle Nav
    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('navActive');

   
    //Burger Animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });

    
}

navSlide();
```

```css
*{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Nav bar*/
/*Background Menu*/

nav.menu {

    width:100%;
    height: 85px;
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 16px 3px;
}


/*Costumização do body */

body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
body .menu{
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}

/*Costumização logo */



.ulLogo li  {

    list-style: none;
}


.ulLogo li a img{

    width: 180px;
    float:left;
    padding: 19px 0px 0px 60px;

}
/*Transição Logo Opacity*/
.ulLogo li a img#espiral:hover {

    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity 300ms linear 0s;
}
.ulLogo li a img#espiral:not(:hover) {

    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 399ms linear 0s;
}

/*Costumização sections */
nav .ulSecções {

    float: left;
    padding-left: 90px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li{ 

    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 90px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li a{

    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", "Palatino", sans-serif ;
    color:rgb(192, 163, 68);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border: none;
    background: none;

    padding: 0px 18px;
}

nav ul.ulSecções li a i{

    font-size: 15px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    visibility: hidden;

}
nav ul.ulSecções li a i#shop{

    visibility: visible;
}
nav ul.ulSecções li a.loja{

    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

/* Transition das anchors */

nav ul.ulSecções li a:hover {

    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: color 150ms ease-in 0s,
                opacity 150ms ease-in 0s;

}

nav ul.ulSecções li a:not(:hover) {

    color: rgb(204, 174, 75);
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: color 150ms ease-in 0s,
                opacity 150ms ease-in 0s;

}

/*DropDowns*/

/*Dropdown Geral e Carla Ornelas*/
nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown {

    display: none;
    position: absolute;

    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    border-radius: 1px 1px 6px 6px;
}

nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown#dropdownCarlaOrnelas {

    bottom: -195px;
}

nav .ulSecções li:hover ul.dropdown  {

    display: block;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover ul.dropdown#dropdownCarlaOrnelas li  {

    width: 278px;
}


nav ul.ulSecções li ul.dropdown li a {

    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-right: 80px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: "Lato", "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    font-size: 14px;
}


/*Dropdown Cursos*/

nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown#cursos {

    bottom: -45px;
}

nav .ulSecções li:hover ul.dropdown#cursos li  {

    width: 140px;
}

/*Dropdown Conteúdos*/

nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown#conteúdos {

    bottom: -45px;
}

nav .ulSecções li:hover ul.dropdown#conteúdos li  {

    width: 210px;
}

/*Dropdown Recursos*/
nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown#recursos {

    bottom: -145px;
}

nav .ulSecções li:hover ul.dropdown#recursos li  {

    width: 264px;
}


      /*DropDown Transitions (text)*/
nav ul.ulSecções li ul.dropdown li a:hover {

    color: rgb(190, 172, 100);
    transition: color 150ms ease-in 0s;

    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    transition: letter-spacing 150ms ease-in 0s;
}

/*Animation da Dropdown */
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown {
    perspective: 1000px;
}

nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown {
    transform-origin: top center;
    opacity:0;
}

nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown:nth-child(1) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: -150ms;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown:nth-child(2) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: 0ms;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown:nth-child(3) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: 150ms;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown:nth-child(4) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: 300ms;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown:nth-child(5) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: 450ms;
}

/*li animation Part*/
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown li {
    transform-origin: top center;
    opacity:0;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown li:nth-child(1) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: -150ms;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown li:nth-child(2) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
   animation-delay: 0ms;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown li:nth-child(3) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: 150ms;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown li:nth-child(4) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: 300ms;
}
nav .ulSecções li:hover > ul.dropdown li:nth-child(5) {
    animation: animate 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-delay: 450ms;
}

/*Mobile Nav Bar*/


.show, input{

    display: none;
}

.burger{

    display: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 31px 49px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{

    width: 27px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(192, 163, 68);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotateX(20deg);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

/*Toggle burger*/

.toggle .line1{

    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}
.toggle .line2{
    opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}

/*Mobile screen adjustments*/

/*Mobile S*/
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){

    body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /*Nav bar*/
    nav.menu {

        width:100%;
        height: 140px;
    }
    .ulLogo li  {
        
        margin-left: 25%;
    }
    .ulLogo li a img {
        
        width: 400px;
    }
    .ulSecções  {

    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 51vh;
    top: 139px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 400ms ease-out 0s;
    }
    nav ul.ulSecções li a{

        font-size: 35px;
        text-align: center;

        padding:  18px;
    }
    nav ul.ulSecções li a.loja{

        font-size: 35px;
    }
    nav ul.ulSecções li a i{

        font-size: 35px;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /*Dropdowns*/

    nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown {

        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    
        width: 500px;
        background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
        border-radius: 1px 1px 6px 6px;
    }
    /*carla ornelas*/
    nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown#dropdownCarlaOrnelas {
    
        bottom: 30px;
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
    }

    nav .ulSecções li:hover ul.dropdown#dropdownCarlaOrnelas li  {
    
        width: 500px;
    }
    
    /*Dropdown Cursos*/

    nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown#cursos {

        bottom: 25px;
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
    }

    nav .ulSecções li:hover ul.dropdown#cursos li  {

        width: 500px;
    }

    /*Dropdown Conteúdos*/

    nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown#conteúdos {

        bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
    }

    nav .ulSecções li:hover ul.dropdown#conteúdos li  {

        width: 500px;
    }

    /*Dropdown Recursos*/
    nav .ulSecções li ul.dropdown#recursos {

        bottom: 10px;
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
    }

    nav .ulSecções li:hover ul.dropdown#recursos li  {

        width: 500px;
    }

    nav ul.ulSecções li ul.dropdown li a {

        position: relative;
        display: block;
        line-height: 35px;
        padding-right: 80px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-family: "Ubuntu", "Palatino", sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        font-size: 28px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    /*Burger*/
    div.burger{
        display: block;
        padding-right: 100px;
        padding-top: 57px;
    }
    .burger div{

        width: 40px;
        height: 5px;
        margin: 4px;
    }
}

.navActive{
    transform: translateX(0%)
}
```

```html
<!--Nav Bar-->
  <header>
  <nav class="menu">   
    <div>
     <ul class="ulLogo">
      <li><a href="#" title="Carla Ornelas Logo"> <img src="../Logo-(3).png"/> </a></li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
    <div>
    <ul class="ulSecções">
     <li> <a href="../Main page/index.html" title="Home">Home</a> </li>
     <li class="carla"> <a class="carlaOrnelas" href="#" title="Carla Ornelas">Carla Ornelas</a>
      <ul class="dropdown" id="dropdownCarlaOrnelas">
       <li><a href="/Carla Ornelas/sobre.html" title="Sobre">Sobre</a></li>
       <li><a href="/Carla Ornelas/programas.html" title="Empowered Women">Empowered Women</a> </li>
       <li><a href="" title="Cadastro">Cadastro</a> </li>
       <li><a href="/Carla Ornelas/depoimentos.html" title="Depoimentos">Depoimentos</a> </li>  
      </ul> 
     </li>
     <li><a href="#" title="Cursos">Cursos</a>
       <ul class="dropdown" id="dropdownProgramas">
         <li><a href="" title="Online">Online</a></li>  
        </ul> 
       </li>
     <li><a href="" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
 
     <li> <a href="" title="Contatos">Contatos</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="" title="Acesse a nosa loja" class="loja">Loja <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
  </nav>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you provide this meta tag inside your `<head></head>` to prevent bugs.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a lot of fixed sizes of things. I would try to use percentages (%) instead of pixels (px) to make it more responsive.

Comment: Also, your question is unclear. What exactly do you want the nav bar to do or look like in the mobile view?